# Hybrid equivalence of Polynomial-like maps

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I am reading Douady and Hubbards "On the dynamics of polynomial-like mappings". I am relatively new dynamics of complex maps, and I would appreciate some help with aspects of the following.

**Definition:** Let $f:U'\rightarrow U$ and $g: V'\rightarrow V$ be two polynomial-like maps. They are termed *quasi-conformally equivalent* if there exists a quasi-conformal map $\phi$ sending a neighbourhood of $K(f)$ to a neighbourhood of $K(g)$ such that $\phi\circ f = g\circ\phi$. They are termed *hybrid equivalent* if additionally $\phi$ can be chosen such that $\bar\partial\phi=0$ on $K(f)$.

What does the symbol "$\bar\partial\phi$" represent in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z}$, the [Wirtinger derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) defined by 
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z} := \frac 12 \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\right) $$

Comment: That is helpful! Why the $1/2$ factor may I ask?

Comment: We want to have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z} = 1$ for $f(z) = \bar z$.